# SQL Server Select count (select count where) where ... group by

Tags: select, count, sql-server-2008

у меня есть таблица TICKET там есть столбцы session, DEALDATE и Transactio.

в session находиться значение например s7, ut, u6 итд

в DEALDATE дата каждой операции

в Transactio находиться транзакция например Продажа или Возврат

мне удалось сделать отчет по дням(DEALDATE) количество продаж(Transactio) по значению(session)

```
select * from(
SELECT CAST(DEALDATE as DATE) as date, session, count(id_T)as qtty
FROM TICKET
where (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='2020-03-01' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='2020-03-10') and  Transactio like'%Продажа%'
group by DEALDATE, session) as x
pivot (
SUM(x.qtty)
FOR x.session IN ([ЮТ], [ТКП], [ТФ], [S7])
) piv
order by piv.date desc
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь мне нужно сделать минус количество Транзакций(Возврат) по дням и по значению в этом запросе

сделал еще один count по Transactio = 'Возврат' но выходить непонятные цифры

```
select * from(
SELECT CAST(DEALDATE as DATE) as date, session, count(id_T)-(SELECT count(id_T) 
FROM TICKET WHERE Transactio like'%Возврат%' 
and (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='2020-03-01' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='2020-03-10')) as qtty
FROM TICKET
where (cast(DEALDATE as date)>='2020-03-01' and cast(DEALDATE as date)<='2020-03-10') and  Transactio like'%Продажа%'
group by DEALDATE, session) as x
pivot (
SUM(x.qtty)
FOR x.session IN ([ЮТ], [ТКП], [ТФ], [S7])
) piv
order by piv.date desc
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне сделать чтобы если на дату 21/03/2020 было 10 продаж и 3 возврата по session S7 показало 7 продаж

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы в первом запросе использовал `SUM` вместо `COUNT`

```
SELECT …, SUM(CASE WHEN Transactio like'%Продажа%' THEN +1 WHEN Transactio like'%Возврат%' THEN -1 END) as qtty
```

и убрал бы `and Transactio like'%Продажа%'` из `WHERE`